# Django: CeleryBeat with Supervisor on server doesn't schedule periodic task

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, supervisord

I have fully working Django 1.8.5 + Celery 3.1.18 on localhost with periodic task settings.
But on server (Ubuntu 14.04) i need additional file celerybeat.conf (first is celery.conf) to make periodic tasks working on server.
If i launch manually celery on server simple tasks are working (UPD: also periodic tasks works too with -B option):

```
celery worker -A engine -B -l debug
```

but if run with Supervisor it starts, detect periodic task (in settings.py django) but do nothing. No errors in logs (only warnings), no task scheduling

```
sudo supervisorctl reread
sudo supervisorctl restart celery
```

How to fix?

here is settings.py

```
# Celery settings

BROKER_URL = 'django://'

from kombu.serialization import registry
registry.enable('pickle')
import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()

CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES=3600
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json' #json pickle msgpack
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_IMPORTS=["wall.tasks"]
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Africa/Nairobi'
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = "djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler"
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE_FILENAME = '/var/lib/celery/beat.db'

SECRET_KEY = 'nbx.........#)i0onegi)as%d80hpcxp98%d9sphh^aqgt'
from celery.schedules import crontab
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'get_all_data': {
        'task': 'tasks.get_all_data',
        'schedule': crontab(minute="*/4"),
        #'args': (16, 16),
    },
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the worker with an additional `-B` flag (for beat). This flag also has to be provided in CELERY_OPTS settings in a daemon's config file

Comment: @schwobaseggl Yes: in celery.conf tried to add -B:   command=/usr/local/bin/celery worker -A engine --loglevel=INFO     Also in celerybeat.conf command=/usr/local/bin/celery worker -A engine -B --loglevel=INFO   but both variants dont work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post your celerybeat.conf and supervisord.conf here?
I have found a very good tutorial at http://www.lexev.org/en/2014/django-celery-setup/

Comment: I have used another tutorial, think my mistake was not reload settings of Supervisor: sudo supervisorctl reload. I have done sudo supervisorctl reread and thought this will update settings, but it is not. Now all works